# Save Profile takes Code Blocks out?

Tags: discussion, bug, profile-page

When I include a code block in my "About Me" it will save fine. But when I go to edit it, the code block becomes regular text, not a big deal when its only one line but still thought it should be brought up.

This occurs on all stack sites. At first I thought it was Site specific but it happens to be the same on all the sites.

Screenshots:

[image: Unedited]

[image: Edit Screen]